# does it matter where I place app.use(helmet... within the app.use statements?

Tags: node.js, express, iframe, clickjacking, helmet.js

I have a node.js application where I'm using multiple app.use statements. I want to include the `app.use(helmet.frameguard({ action: 'deny' }));` line to prevent clickjacking by preventing my site from appearing in iframes and I wanted to ask whether it matters where I place this line in the order of the app.use statements? Do I need to place it in a particular place amongst all the other app.use statements (e.g. `app.use(cookie-parser());`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean it does, all middleware run line by line or you can say synchronously.

Just make sure to you should place it above route initialization (since if it goes to routes it might be possible that you are returning the function response from there only, so it wont go to next middleware, since response already sent). Can paste it above or below cookie-parser.

Answer (score 1):

*Summary: I recommend putting `helmet()` first.*

Helmet maintainer here. This is more of an Express question than a Helmet question.

Express apps run their middleware in sequence. For example, the following will print `foo`, then `bar`, for every request:

```js
function fooMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  console.log("foo");
  next();
}

function barMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  console.log("bar");
  next();
}

app.use(fooMiddleware);
app.use(barMiddleware);

// ...
```

Alternatively, this will print `bar`, then `foo`:

```js
app.use(barMiddleware);
app.use(fooMiddleware);
```

So if you want Helmet's headers to be applied to all responses, it's important to put them first.

For example, this will set the Helmet headers for every request:

```js
const app = express();

app.use(helmet());

// ...
```

But this one might not, because the static file middleware might get to it first:

```js
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("./static_files"));

app.use(helmet());

// ...
```

It's worth noting that route handlers (like `app.get('/foo')`) are conceptually very similar to middleware. These two code snippets are nearly the same (though you should use the former in a real application):

```js
app.get("/foo", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello world!");
});
```

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.method === "GET" && req.url === "/foo") {
    res.send("Hello world!");
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```